# How do I get an icon to change as soon as it is clicked rather than wait for the rest of the page to render

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am creating an accordian effect using [Boostrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/).

I have customised the button to show a down icon to expand and an up icon to collapse using jquery click event.

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card bg-primary myRounded">
    <div class="card-eader bg-white myRounded" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button id="btnExpand" class="btn btn-link float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery.

```
$('#btnExpand').click(function() {
  $('.collapse')
    .on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .find(".fa-chevron-circle-down")
        .removeClass("fa-chevron-circle-down")
        .addClass("fa-chevron-circle-up");
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
      $(this)
        .parent()
        .find(".fa-chevron-circle-up")
        .removeClass("fa-chevron-circle-up")
        .addClass("fa-chevron-circle-down");
    });
});
```

An example can be found here:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicksbell/aq5b786c/32/)

The issue I have is that the icon doesn't change immediately when you click it, it waits for the expanded/collapsed dropdown to be rendered first.  If you click the down arrow you will see that there is a slight delay before the up icon is displayed and vice versa.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that icon changes as soon as the button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the `#btnExpand` click handler is not needed. You should just listen for the Bootstrap events when the page loads.

The issue itself is because you're using the `shown` and `hidden` events which only fire when the animation *ends*. To perform the action when the animation starts, use `show` and `hide` instead. For reference, here's the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) covering the behaviour of those events.

As an aside you can also improve your logic by using `toggleClass()` instead of separate `addClass()`/`removeClass()` calls.

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-circle-down").toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up");
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".fa-chevron-circle-up").toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-up fa-chevron-circle-down");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r9yngp72/)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.  And thanks for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution, but I changes the jQuery to be the following and it seems to be doing what your looking for

```
$('#btnExpand').click(function() {
      if($(this).find('i').hasClass('fa-chevron-circle-down')){
          $(this)
             .find('.fa-chevron-circle-down')
             .removeClass("fa-chevron-circle-down")
             .addClass("fa-chevron-circle-up");
      } else {
          $(this)
             .find('.fa-chevron-circle-up')
             .removeClass("fa-chevron-circle-up")
             .addClass("fa-chevron-circle-down");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is the animation changing immediately on click, you can reduce your code by quite a bit by simply toggling the correct class on click. The rest of the code seems a bit overkill.

Instead, if you replace the entire Jquery code you shared, with the following, it should do the trick:

```
$('#btnExpand').click(function() {
    $('.fas').toggleClass("fa-chevron-circle-up");
});
```